# Local storage for login

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, local-storage

I want to see if users on my site have logged on more than one time so they have to log back in. When I run my code, the h4 element has no text content inside of it. Also, the h4 does not have any text at first and it waits for the code to give its HTML. However, Chrome does tell me that there is localStorage. I think it is how that I am trying to get it is the problem. The other problem that the code looks correct for me. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
    var login = 0;
    window.onload = function() {
    login++;
    localStorage.setItem("save1", btoa(login));
    CheckForOtherLogin();
    };
    function CheckForOtherLogin() {
    window.localStorage.getItem("save1");
    if (login === null) {
     login = 0;
    } else {
     login = atob(login);
     document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = login;
    }
    }
```

Edit: Looks like I made a little tiny mistake:

```
    var login = 0;
    window.onload = function() {
    login++;
    localStorage.setItem("save1", login);
    CheckForOtherLogin();
    };
    function CheckForOtherLogin() {
    window.localStorage.getItem("save1");
    if (login === null) {
     login = 0;
    } else {
     document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = login;
    }
return login;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that what your're passing to the localstorage is an object so the html won't read it, also in the "CheckForOtherLogin()" function you need to asign a value to the var "login" when you get the value from the localStorage just try this:

```
`var login = 0;
window.onload = function() {
  login++;
  localStorage.setItem("save1", login);
  CheckForOtherLogin();
};
function CheckForOtherLogin() {
  login = window.localStorage.getItem("save1");
  if (login === null) {
    login = 0;
  } else {
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = login;
  }
}`
```